# PushSharp OnNotificationSent event not trigger when push notification sent to Android but its trigger when sent to iphone

Tags: c#, pushsharp

**I am using PushSharp library to send PushNotification From .net to android and iphone**

**my android and iphone recieving push notification sent from .net but in** 
**.net OnNotificationSent event trigger only for ios and not for android**

```
    **My PushSharp registration code** 

  push = new PushBroker();
    push.OnNotificationSent += NotificationSent;
    push.OnChannelException += ChannelException;
    push.OnServiceException += ServiceException;
    push.OnNotificationFailed += NotificationFailed;
    push.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += DeviceSubscriptionExpired;
    push.OnDeviceSubscriptionChanged += DeviceSubscriptionChanged;
    push.OnChannelCreated += ChannelCreated;
    push.OnChannelDestroyed += ChannelDestroyed;

    push.RegisterGcmService(new GcmPushChannelSettings(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["PushNotificationApiKey"]));


    string basePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "Certificates/Certificate.p12");

    byte[] appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);
    push.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(false, appleCert, ""));
```

Comment: I can tell from your code that you are using a very old version of PushSharp. Try updating to  v.4 first. They fixed a lot of bugs in the meantime, maybe this will already solve your problem.